# cakephp 3 execute an action without going to it view

Tags: cakephp, action, http-redirect

i i have an Registration form and this form i have in login.ctp this is how it looks:

```
<--Here is the login code-->
---
<--Here is the end of login code-->

<--Here start the Singup code-->

                             <div class="form-bottom">
    <?= $this->Form->create('Registration', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'singup')));?>
            <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->control('email', array('placeholder'=>'Email','class'=>'form-email form-control'));?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->input('password', array('type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Password','class'=>'form-password form-control'));?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
     <?= $this->Form->input('cPassword', array('label' => 'Confirm Password','placeholder'=>'Confirm Password', 'title' => 'Confirm password','class'=>'form-password form-control', 'type'=>'password'));?>
                                    </div>

    <?= $this->Form->submit('Singup', array('class'=>'btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0','style'=>'float:right'));?>
     <?= $this->Form->end();?>
```

The Problem is when i fill email, password and confirm password input right and when i press singup button its work but when i give some wrong(that don't pass the validation) email or password and something like this, it redirect me to **Users/singup**. What i want is to disable redirecting , how can i do this?

Comment: When a user fails to authenticate with username and password it's redirecting to the sign up form? That is not default behavior of the Auth component. Can you please share what you're doing in your login action.

Comment: i finde a solution i just put an redirect to de login.ctp . It was the best way soo when it turs error that shows me on the same page.If you understand what i mean.